# Perl subroutine doesn't return value

Tags: perl, function, return-value, subroutine

Sorry to disturb you with such a silly question, I'm new at Perl. 
 
I'm trying to modify parsing subroutine, written by my colleague and have problems with functions in perl. 
It returns empty value, I don't understand why? Have already read reference sites, seen examples and they are obvious. Here's the code of function:

```
sub parseHTML
{
    my ($node, $depth) = @_;
    my $str = ' ';
    if (ref $node) 
    {
        if ($node->tag () ne "script" && $node->tag () ne "style")
        {
            my @children = $node->content_list ();
            for my $child_node (@children) 
            {
                parseHTML ($child_node, $depth + 1);
            }
        }
    }

    else 
    {
        $str = $str.$node."\n";
        #print $str;
    }
    return $str;
}
```

And then I try to use it:

```
my $parser = HTML::TreeBuilder->new ();
$parser->parse ($cont);
my $Parsed = parseHTML ($parser, 0);
print "$Parsed\n";
#parseHTML ($parser, 0);
```

The return value is empty. However, if I decide to print data right in function, uncomment string:
`print $str;` and use `parseHTML ($parser, 0);` instead, it works, and there's an output. 
Where could be the mistake? Data in function seems to be local.
Here's the [complete code](http://pastebin.com/0MUn03VJ) listing as well.

Comment: $str is not changed in `ref $node` == true section.

Comment: You never set the value of `$str` in the true section of your if statement.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want just `$node->as_text`?

Comment: Thanks, everybody, now I understand

Comment: @Borodin, I didn't know it's possible... :) So, everything is simplier?)

Comment: @Tofrar: `as_text` does the same as you (badly mis-named) `parseHTML` seems to be attempting. It even ignores `style` and `script` tags.

Comment: @Borodin, thanx. So, how should it be? `my $parser = HTML::TreeBuilder->new ();
$result = $parser->parse ($cont)->as_text;` or I need to modify function?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to concat the $str returning from parseHTML

```
$str .= parseHTML ($child_node, $depth + 1);
```

or you can use a pointer this way:

```
...
my $Parsed;
parseHTML ($parser, 0,\$Parsed);
....

sub parseHTML
{
    my ($node, $depth, $out) = @_;
    my $str = ' ';
    if (ref $node)
    {
        if ($node->tag() ne "script" && $node->tag() ne "style")
        {
            my @children = $node->content_list ();
            for my $child_node (@children)
            {
                parseHTML ($child_node, $depth + 1,$out);
            }
         }
    }

    else
    {
        $$out .= $node."\n";
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You forgot to add to `$str` in the "then" part of the `if`.

```
parseHTML ($child_node, $depth + 1);
```

should be

```
$str .= parseHTML ($child_node, $depth + 1);
```